# SQL - query result store in column

Tags: sql, sql-server

Very newbish question, but how do I store a query result into a column. I would like to update the table. I wrote a query to find the modus of articles based on their prices. I have created a column "modus" and the query has the requested result. Now I want to add the query result to the column "modus" corresponding with the article_code, so that I can use the modus data for other analysis. Query below.

```
SELECT article_code, MAX(price) AS modus_1
FROM (
       SELECT 
         [rank] = RANK() OVER (                           
                                PARTITION BY article_code   
                                ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC 
                                ) 
       , COUNT(*) [#]
       , article_code
       , price      
       FROM dbo.import_company
       GROUP BY article_code, price
) AS ranked
WHERE ranked.[rank] = 1
GROUP BY article_code
```

Query result:

```
Article_code --- Modus  
00023 --- 305  
00067 --- 323  
00075 --- 53,2  
00535 --- 438  
00583 --- 664  
00600 --- 608  
00617 --- 535  
00637 --- 535  
00673 --- 491  
00674 --- 522
```

Now I would like to store the modus result into the modus column.

Comment: Do want to update a table?  If so, what table?  Sample data and desired results are very helpful.

Comment: Hint: You need to alter the table to add the column and then use UPDATE statement based on article_code to feed your values into table rows.

Comment: I have never seen group by and partition by used together. Be careful, you are treading on dangerous ground.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update the table by joining your query:

```
update ic
set modus = t.modus_1
from dbo.import_company ic inner join (
  <your query here>
) t on t.article_code = ic.article_code and t.price = ic.price -- maybe the condition for price is not needed
```

You can remove: `and t.price = ic.price` if you want to join only on `article`.